# Merge multiple commits on different branches

Tags: git, git-merge

I committed several pull requests to an open source project here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pulls

They are each very small and It was requested that I merge them all into one pull request.

I have a fork here with several branches that need to be merged.

https://github.com/reggi/node/branches/yours

Is this command the best way to go?

```
git merge --squash origin/patch-1 origin/patch-3 origin/patch-4 origin/patch-5 origin/patch-6 origin/patch-7 origin/patch-8 origin/patch-9 origin/patch-10 origin/patch-11 origin/patch-12 origin/patch-13
```

How do I merge all of these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in three steps:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git merge [list of your patch-branches]`
3. `git rebase -i [ref to the first commit in master before any commits from your branches]`

In the third step, you should check 'squash' option for all commits except the first.

And I highly recommend creating a backup of your repo before experimenting with git rebase. :)